# Invalid app link URL on Careers profile page

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I am trying to add a link to an app I worked on to my Careers 2.0 profile page. The problem is that when I press "get project" invalid URL (not the one I input) gets added to profile.

I investigated possible causes and it seems that my target page has invalid og:url meta tag (pointing to root). This is not my page and I cannot edit it; neither can I edit the link on Careers profile manually.

I think one should be able to manually edit the links added to profile.

Can anyone offer a workaround for my issue?

Comment: Can you tell us what link you're trying to add, so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'd rather not reveal it publicly. Can I message you in private?

Comment: Sure, email careers@stackoverflow.com with the link (and also include the link to this post) and somebody will take a look.

Comment: Thank you. Email sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushed a fix. Apparently, we were truncating some URLs on the backend before they were saved to the database and put on the public CV. Should be all set.

Comment: It works now. Thank you.